# Confidence Interval for a Binomial

Tags: probability, statistics

Having trouble with this question from my textbook. I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

The following set of $10$ data points are independent realizations from a Binomial model
$X$ ~ $\mathrm{Bin}(36,\pi)$
$$10,12, 7, 6, 6,11, 7,12, 9,10.$$

Compute numerically, showing all your work, the $95$% confidence interval for $\pi$.

I know that the confidence interval for a binomial looks like this:

$$p\pm z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$

But I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if we took a sample of $36$, then did it again, and again, until we had a sample of $360$. The $10$ numbers $10$, $12$, $7$, and so on represent the number of successes in the various trials.

We can lump all these trials together. What we had was in effect $360$ independent Bernoulli trials, and, if I am adding correctly, a total of $90$ successes.

Thus the **sample proportion** of successes is $\frac{90}{360}=0.25$.

The true probability $\pi$ of success is unknown. However, the random variable represented by the sample mean has mean $\pi$, and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{360}}$.

Because $360$ is fairly large, we can expect that the true standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{360}}$  is well-approximated by $\sqrt{\frac{(0.25)(1-0.25)}{360}}$. Call this number $s$.

Note that $s\approx 0.02282$.

By the normal approximation, a $95\%$ confidence interval for $\pi$ is 
$$0.25-1.96s \le \pi \le 0.25+1.96s.$$